# How do i split an input string into a smaller string and compare them

Tags: java

I just started picking up Java and ran into a problem with this practice question. I am supposed to print the number of duplicated lines in an input. Any help would be appreciated!

Sample input:
test
test
TesT

Sample output:
2

Here is my attempt that did not work:

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count=0;
        while(scan.hasNext()) {
            String s = scan.nextLine()+"\n";
            String first=s.split("\n")[0];
            for (int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
                if(first==s.split("\n")[i])
                    count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `scan.nextLine()` already reads a single line. Putting a `"\n"` at the end of it, splitting on `"\n"` and getting the first result is equivalent to just doing `scan.nextLine()`.

Comment: Also, you're mixing `hasNext` with `nextLine`.

Comment: you should use String.equals() to compare string

Answer (score 0):

Please try this - if you are using Java8, and the intent is to count duplicate lines(not words) and see if it helps. This is using input from the file "error.txt" in your local anywhere.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
            Map<String, Long> dupes = Files.lines(Paths.get("/Users/hdalmia/Documents/error.txt"))
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                            Collectors.counting()));

        
            dupes.forEach((k, v)-> System.out.printf("(%d) times : %s ....%n",
                    v, k.substring(0,  Math.min(50, k.length()))));
        }
```

My File had input as

hello

hello

hi

Output was :

(1) times : hi ....

(2) times : hello ....

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add [a Java Map](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-map) to memorize what input lines you've already encountered, something like

```
public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Map map=new HashMap();  
    int count=0;
    while(scan.hasNext()) {
        String s = scan.nextLine()+"\n";
        if(map.hasKey(s)) count++;
        else map.put(s, true);
    }
    System.out.println(count); 
  }
}
```

You can read more about this topic here [dynamic-programming](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming/)